# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'hours' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `payrolls` () values ())

Tags: laravel

I am trying to insert 'employee_id' that belongs to employees table into payrolls table, but i keep getting this error despite having `$fillable = ['over_time', 'notified','hours','rate', 'gross', 'employee_id']`, is there any other solution to this?

```
Schema::create('payrolls', function (Blueprint $table) { 
     $table->bigIncrements('id'); $table->boolean('over_time')->default(0); 
      $table->boolean('notified')->default(0);        
      $table->integer('hours')->nullable(0);
      $table->integer('rate')->nullable(0); 
      $table->integer('gross')->nullable(0); 
      $table->softDeletes(); $table->timestamps(); 
    });
```

Comment: You have not defined any default value to `hours` column and inserting blank value to `hours` column

Comment: Here is the migration code `Schema::create('payrolls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->boolean('over_time')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('notified')->default(0);
            $table->integer('hours')->nullable(0);
            $table->integer('rate')->nullable(0);
            $table->integer('gross')->nullable(0);

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

Answer (score 0):

As per your migration you have defined `hours` columns `nullable` false that means it cannot be null and also no `default` value is defined for that column.

Due to some reason your `hours` is going blank in your request that is why you are getting this error.

```
$table->integer('hours')->nullable(0);
```

To resolve this either define default value to your hour column as below or pass a valid value to `hours` column

```
$table->integer('hours')->default("00");
```

Comment: Then how should i edit `hours` column to make it `nullable` true?

Comment: to make hours column nullable you don't need to pass `0`. Just use `$table->integer('hours')->nullable()`

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer. It will help other.